# iOS re-routing requests w/ GCDWebServer (not redirecting)

Tags: ios, network-programming, gcdwebserver

I want to create a server on iOS with `GCDWebServer`, which will accept request to `localhost`, and then, draw the data from another `url` (a video file) and stream the data to the response. I intend to use plain `NSURLConnection`, and in the `didReceiveData` of the `NSURLConnection` callback, I want to pass this data to the `GCDWebServerResponse`.

I am having a hard time to figure out how can I keep the connection from a request open, so that I can initiate another request w/ `NSURLConnection`, and start serving data to the response.

Is there any way I can do that? Do I need to create a new subclass of `GCDWebServerStreamedResponse`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to subclass `GCDWebServerStreamedResponse` but simply instantiate it and use the `GCDWebServerAsyncStreamBlock` callback.

In the callback, create your `NSURLConnection` and have it run asynchronously. Then whenever new data is available (e.g. from `-didReceiveData:`), pass it through using the `GCDWebServerBodyReaderCompletionBlock` and when there is no more data available, pass an empty NSData.

See the "Advanced asynchronous version" in the [GCDWebServer README](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer#asynchronous-http-responses) for a similar concept.